# T-SQL Rounding to 0.0, 0.5, or 1.0

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by, rounding

I have an interesting issue where I need to round the result of an AVG() function in a specific manner for use in the ORDER BY clause.

These are for use in recipe ratings.

Examples of the rounding formula:

```
1.2 -> 1
1.4 -> 1
1.5 -> 1.5
1.6 -> 2
1.9 - >2
```

I am querying for a list of recipes, and they needed to be ordered so that a recipe with one 5-star rating is not ordered a above a recipe with 100 ratings that average 4.9. The second part of the order by clause is the count of ratings.

If this requires a user defined function, I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (Num % 1) = .5
        THEN Num
        ELSE ROUND(Num,0)
    END
```

Comment: These seems to make sense and looks like it should work. I'm having issues with Num being an Invalid Column Name. Any reason why it wouldn't work if Num (in your example) was found from a sub query in the SELECT.

SELECT otherStuff, Num = (SELECT Avg(Rating) FROM table2) 
FROM table1

Comment: @danomite That would be a issue since `Num` is not a column. Either use a join, or wrap the current query inside a subquery: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT otherstuff, (SELECT Avg(Rating) FROM table2) AS Num FROM table1) ORDER BY CASE...`

Comment: I'm marking this as Accepted - turns out they want it rounding to the nearest half now... Now they finally listen...This should satisfy the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you have stars and half-stars?
I'd suggest `ORDER BY ROUND(value*2, 0)/2`, this way it rounds to closest `0.5` (half-star) step.

Comment: OP doesn't want to round to the closest half. `1.4 -> 1` not `1.5`

Comment: Yep I've noticed that, just thought that by common sense (stars/halfstars) he would. :)

Comment: I.e. if recipe with 100 ratings with average 4.9 should round to 5 stars and rank higher than recipe with single 5-star rating, why recipe with 100 ratings averaging 1.4 would rank lower than recipe with single 1.5-star rating? However it's just my guess of course, and your solution is correct according to OP's examples.

Comment: They're finally agreeing to the nearest half star. This will definitely do it :)